# What exactly is leading to "Error: 3 INVALID_ARGUMENT: Unable to extract text from document" error using google translate library?

Tags: google-translate, google-api-nodejs-client

I have used [google translate nodejs library](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/libraries/v3/nodejs) to implement document translation in one of the server application. I've used [advanced edition](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/advanced/translate-documents) method to translate the document.
I'm getting an invalid argument error while processing a word document(.docx) with the language pairs are Macedonian -> English.

The request body is like the following object:

```
{
        parent: PROJECT_LOCATION,
        sourceLanguageCode,
        targetLanguageCode,
        documentInputConfig:
        {
            mimeType: mimeTypeObj[mimeType], // mime types: text/plain, text/html
            gcsSource: {
                inputUri: inputUri + uploadedUrl,
            },
        },
        documentOutputConfig: {
            gcsDestination: {
                outputUriPrefix: outputUri + fileFolder + '/output/',
            },
        }
```